# Error in using Stacks to implement Queue (JAVA)

Tags: java

I encountered an strange problem when I used Stacks to implement Queue. Could anyone give me an idea?
When I wrote the code like this, it was wrong. Because if I create a object of MyQueue, and then push(1) push(2) pop, it will return 1. However it should be 2.

```
class MyQueue {
Stack<Integer> s1=new Stack<Integer>();
Stack<Integer> s2=new Stack<Integer>();
// Push element x to the back of queue.
public void push(int x) {
    s1.push(x);
}

// Removes the element from in front of queue.
public void pop() {
    if(s2.size()!=0)
        s2.pop();
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i<s1.size(); i++){
            s2.push(s1.pop());                
        }
        s2.pop();
    }
}
}
```

But if I modify the code like below, it is correct, but I cannot find the difference between these two classes.

```
class MyQueue {
Stack<Integer> s1=new Stack<Integer>();
Stack<Integer> s2=new Stack<Integer>();
// Push element x to the back of queue.
public void push(int x) {
    s1.push(x);
}

// Removes the element from in front of queue.
public void pop() {
    if(!s2.empty())
        s2.pop();
    else{
        while(!s1.empty())
            s2.push(s1.pop());                
        s2.pop();
    }
}
}
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your `for` loop you increment `i` while at the same time `s1.size()` is decreasing. Imagine `s1` has 5 elements at the beginning.

1. iteration: `i` = 0, `s1.size()` = 5
2. iteration: `i` = 1, `s1.size()` = 4
3. iteration: `i` = 2, `s1.size()` = 3
4. iteration: `i` = 3, `s1.size()` = 2

The loop will stop because `i < s1.size()` is now `false` even though there are still elements in `s1`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `for` loop in the first example:

```
for(int i = 0; i<s1.size(); i++){
      s2.push(s1.pop());                
}
```

Let's say the `size` of `s1` is 2 once we push two elements. Now, after first iteration, one element is popped from `s1` and hence, `size` becomes 1. As the breaking condition is `i < s1.size()` (`i` is 1 after first iteration), it breaks out of loop and one element is left in s1.

Second example uses while loop and hence, no such condition arises.

Also, I would recommend changing return type of `pop` method to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
for(int i = 0; i<s1.size(); i++){
  s2.push(s1.pop());                
}
```

is not equivalent to

```
while(!s1.empty())
  s2.push(s1.pop());
```

Note that `s1.size()` changes in every iteration, so you will end up terminating the loop before all elements were pop out of `s1`. For example, suppose you have a stack with 4 elements (1, 2, 3 and 4). Then these are the values of `i`, `s1.size()` and the stack elements themselves at the beginning of each iteration:

```
i s1.size() stack
0         4 1,2,3,4
1         3 1,2,3
2         2 1,2 // here the loop stops
```